# how to upload all rows from sqlite to online Mysql

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am creating a app that upload all `sqlite` table rows one by one, but I don't have any idea how can I do it. Please give me idea. Thanks.

Comment: Read the sqlite lines > write the data to the mysql... Where are you encountering issues in your code?

Answer (score 0):

you can make a webservice which accepts the data from row as parameter and then inserts it in mysql table. then take out each row from sqlite database and call the webservice with this data.

Comment: thanks for reply.. but my problem is how to perform this long task

Comment: i have use for loop for getting data from sqlite and uploading on server.But it is not working.

Comment: use loop and get the data and post it as a json to the webservice. A single api call can post the json of whole data read from the sqlite database.